# how to load JSON file into Pandas dataframe, specific errors

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have an assignment and I am trying to load the nutrients.json file into pandas data frame. I am using python 3.5
I have tried two ways

1. data_df=pd.read_json("nutrients.json")

This gives an error "ValueError: Trailing data"

2.
    # read the entire file into a python array
    with open('nutrients.json', 'rb') as f:
        data = f.readlines()

```
# remove the trailing "\n" from each line
data = map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), data)
data = map(str, data)
# each element of 'data' is an individual JSON object.
# i want to convert it into an *array* of JSON objects
# which, in and of itself, is one large JSON object
# basically... add square brackets to the beginning
# and end, and have all the individual business JSON objects
# separated by a comma
data_json_str = "[" + ','.join(data) + "]"

# now, load it into pandas
data_df = pd.read_json(data_json_str)
```

This gives an error

ValueError: Expected object or value

nutrients.json is the file that I extracted using the instructions below. Its a 335 Mb file. Please can you help me here.

Many Thanks for this

1. Check out the nutrient-db python utility from GitHub from https://github.com/schirinos/nutrient-db.git

   2. Run the main program with python nutrientdb.py -e > nutrients.json to convert the USDA data to JSON format. For further details, check https://github.com/schirinos/nutrient-db. You might have to install the python utility for MongoDB interface via pip install pymongo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: don't you mean a pandas dataframe?

Comment: yes yes thats what I meant. I have edited the questions. Any help here? I cant attach the 335MB file...is there something i can do here?

Comment: I would just inspect the last line of the the file with tail or something else. You could also just load it with json.load and see what happens. The string magic you are doing later on is really overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

run your file through jsonlint.com to see if your file is formatted correctly for json.

Your first attempt was written correctly:

```
df= pd.read_json('example_json.json')
```

Comment: I tried but its a 335 MB file. That website requires me to copy paste the contents and when I try to do that, my computer freezes.

Comment: 1.) Can you at least open the file in a text editor (notepad, notepad++) ? If so, break the file up and paste it into jsonlint.com chunks at a time.